# Transfer values from one table to another in MS Excel by matching values in one row to values in a column

Tags: excel, match, row, string-comparison

I am trying to transfer the values in columns p1 through p7 from Table 1 into Table 2. I want to do this by comparing the values in columns A, B, C, and D in Table 1 to the values in column X in Table 2 **which are all strings**. My data set is much larger so I provided a smaller model below.

**Table 1**
[image: Table 1]

**Table 2**
[image: Table 2]

I think I can use the Index and Match functions in Excel to do this based on what is found on [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match) website. The only thing I'm having trouble understanding is how to check for multiple values in one row from Table 1 and compare them to each value in column X of Table 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use **Power Query** instead of a formula. I have been using it for a while and it is way better. It is an add-in for Excel 2010+ (by default in Excel 2016 known as Get and Transform). There you can connect directly any source and transform your data easily.

For your case follow this steps:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. I will check this out tomorrow, it looks promising.

Comment: It is! I stopped using VBA and formulas since I discover this. Microsoft is moving forward in business intelligence!

Comment: Thank you, this works well. The only issue I am having is I cannot save the reordered table onto the same sheet but that's not super important. Maybe you can explain why that is happening?

Comment: It depends on your excel version and the updates. Normally it generates a new sheet for the new data. You can cut and paste and that's it.